Android Studio Scratch output -- What is the correct way to use field
Hi I'd like to know the correct way to assign values to fields in scratch files.
I wished to use scratch to test some logic to convert map to Json with Gson. But I happened to find that when I assigned val a = map.toString() and the output said a = {}.
However if I put val a = map.toString() in a function, and println(a) it gave me the expected result in output panel.
I tried to assign val b = "{${FF.F1}=\"Greeting\"}", and the output panel gave me b = {F1="Greeting"}, which was expected.
I'd like to know why val a = map.toString() outside the function did not assign the value to a. Is there any other things I must notice when using scratch files.
Appreciate any information.
Here is the screenshot:

And this happened in a new created project by Android Studio, I only added Gson to gradle.


